# How to find optimal number of clusters in hierarchical clustering using Gap statistic?

Tags: python, r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, unsupervised-learning

I want to run hierarchical clustering with single linkage to cluster documents with 300 features and 1500 observations. I want to find the optimal number of clusters for this problem.

The below link uses the below code to find the number of clusters with max gap.

http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/determining-the-optimal-number-of-clusters-3-must-known-methods-unsupervised-machine-learning

```
# Compute gap statistic 
set.seed(123)

iris.scaled <- scale(iris[, -5])

gap_stat <- clusGap(iris.scaled, FUN = hcut, K.max = 10, B = 50)

# Plot gap statistic 
fviz_gap_stat(gap_stat)
```

But in the link hcut is not clearly defined. How can I specify single linkage hierarchical clustering to the `clusGap()` function?

Do we have an equivalent of `clusGap()` in python?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `hcut()` function is part of the `factorextra` package used in the link you posted:

> hcut                package:factoextra                 R Documentation
>
> Computes Hierarchical Clustering and Cut the Tree
>
> Description:
>
> ```
>  Computes hierarchical clustering (hclust, agnes, diana) and cut
>  the tree into k clusters. It also accepts correlation based
>  distance measure methods such as "pearson", "spearman" and
>  "kendall".
> ```

R also has a built-in function, `hclust()`, which can be used to perform hierarchical clustering. By default, however, it does not perform single-linkage clustering, so you can't simply replace `hcut` with `hclust`.

If you look at the help for `clusGap()`, however, you will see that you can provide a custom clustering function to be applied:

> FUNcluster: a ‘function’ which accepts as first argument a (data)
>             matrix like ‘x’, second argument, say k, k >= 2, the number
>             of clusters desired, and returns a ‘list’ with a component
>             named (or shortened to) ‘cluster’ which is a vector of length
>             ‘n = nrow(x)’ of integers in ‘1:k’ determining the clustering
>             or grouping of the ‘n’ observations.

The `hclust()` function is able to perform single-linkage hierarchical clustering, so you can do:

```
cluster_fun <- function(x, k) list(cluster=cutree(hclust(dist(x), method="single"), k=k))
gap_stat <- clusGap(iris.scaled, FUN=cluster_fun, K.max=10, B=50)
```